# AI CC - change of increments doesn't work

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this terribly annoying problem:

For some reason, while working on something in Illustrator CC 2015, the keyboard increment (moving objects with the keyboard arrows) changed. it says 0.1 points, but it actually moves the object 16pt, which also happens to be the subdivions of my grids (gridline every: 80pt, subdivisions: 5).

It gets weirder: this only happens in this very AI-file, if I open a different one, everything works as it should...

I've no clue what the problem could be, help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, so copying everything into a new .ai-file (same preferences and everything), worked.
seems to be a bug, but if you come across the same problem, just copy everything, and paste it into a new .ai-file.

Answer (score 0):

What also seems to work: zoom all the way out and search for elements far outside of the artboard. Deleting those can also resolve the problem. It did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and I found out that I accidentally pressed the keyboard shortcut for "Snap to Grid" and it was messing with my keyboard increments.

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue like that, it was a bug, apparently it works correctly if you create the file for "Print" mode, in pts... When creating for Web in pixels the increments and snaps weren't working right.